# Defining large list-within- list array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, grid

I'm attempting to make a Tetris clone in python, and want to make my code more efficient. I want a variable named `board` to be a 20 * 10 array with `False` in each cell, a 2 by 2 example of this being

```
board = [[False, False], [False, False]]
```

When it comes to making a 20 by 10 array of all the same variable, the code gets a bit cumbersome. This is what I've tried to construct the grid:

```
board = [[False * 10] * 22]
```

However, it returns `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`.

I understand why it returns this, but how can I make it return the wanted array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you are multiplying `False` by 10 (0*10), and repeating it 22 times. Hence the result

Try this:

```
board = [[[False] * 10] * 22] #Cast the boolean to a list
```

DEMO

```
>>> [[False] * 10] * 22
[[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

As Ashwini mentioned in the comment, this creates references of the same object in the inner list.

Example:

```
>>> x[0][0] = True
>>> x
[[True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
>>>
```

A work around would be to use:

```
[[False for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(22)]
```

DEMO

```
>>> y = [[False for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(22)]
>>> y
[[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
>>> y[0][0] = True
>>> y
[[True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
>>>
```

Comment: Also creating list this way is still a bad idea, all the inner lists  point to same object.